# How would you phrase this sentence?

Tags: phrases

If I'm talking about, say, an exhibition, and it's going to last for a few months, which one would you say?

- "The exhibition will continue through to May."
- "The exhibition will continue through May."

I even saw it being said this way
"The exhibition continues through May."
and here they're not even talking about a regularly-occurring exhibition, just a one time thing.

Comment: Just want to say that using *through* rather than *until* is a very American construction.

Comment: Only my husband would walk into Wal-Mart and point out the DNA tests and say very loudly thats what we should get everyone for christmas

Answer (score 1):

**The exhibition will continue through May** means the exhibition will continue through the whole of May (or most of it).

**The exhibition will continue through to May** means the exhibition will continue *as far as* May, ie to the end of April or very early days of May, and then stop.

Comment: I figured as much but thought i'd check. Thanks a million! :)